# Laravel 6 artisan package:discover rename bootstrap/cache/packages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

After `composer update` I got an error:

> In Filesystem.php line 146:
>
> rename(/var/www/bootstrap/cache/packages.phpE7r5E4,/var/www/bootstrap/cache
>   /packages.php): No such file or directory

Artisan commands don't work anymore. Already tried:

```
composer du
composer install
composer update
```

Comment: Do `composer dump-autoload` or `artisan cache:clear` help?

Comment: Empty `bootstrap/cache` directory, and run the commands `composer dumpa`, `php artisan optimize:clear`. Try this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, my windows docker (version 2.1.0.3) sometimes fails to execute. I don't know how it looks like the `packages.php` file just got locked. So here is the recipe to fix:

1. I restarted windows,
2. deleted all the files inside `bootstrap\cache`
3. started the containers
4. run `artisan optimize`
5. run `composer du`

Everything went back to work like a magic. :)

Answer (score 2):

run this command: `composer dump-autoload` This command will clean up all compiled files and their paths.

enter this command in your terminal for clear cache: `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and these commands helped me:

```
1. composer dump-autoload 
2. php artisan cache:clear
3. php artisan optimize:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

For me deleting the `composer.lock` file and then running `composer install` fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

or:

```
artisan cache:clear
```

after you update or make changes to `composer.json` to refresh everything.